# Comparing more than 2 doubles at the same time

Tags: java, compare, double, compareto

How do you compare multiple doubles and return a value to see which one is the biggest? I have 4 doubles that I'm trying to compare on the same line and Double.compare only accepts 2 parameters.

I think I have a pretty good understanding on how to compare 2, but I can't figure out how to do more than 2 at once.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use something like `double maxValue = Double.max(a, Double.max(b,c))` to get max of `a` `b` and `c`.

Comment: Other creative solutions: you could use `Arrays.sort` and use the last value in the array, or `DoubleStream.of(...).max()` (note that this might not always be efficient)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the maximum (or minimum), this method "maxOfList" might serve as a template:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Clazz {

    // actual logic
    public static Double maxOfList(final List<Double> doubles) {
        return doubles.stream().max(Double::compareTo).get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // sample data
        var doubles = List.of(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());

        // sample usage
        System.out.println("doubles: " + doubles);
        System.out.println("max:     " + maxOfList(doubles));
    }

}
```